# How do I hide a button using Swift5 when an 'if' condition is true?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to hide a button called "itemOneDelete" when a label ("itemOneLabel") on my View Controller is empty, by using an 'if' loop to change the visibility of the button to "alpha = 0" by using the following code:

```
     @IBAction func itemOneDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if self.itemOneLabel.text == "" {
        itemOneDelete.alpha = 0
    }
```

However I am receiving the following error for the `itemOneDelete.alpha = 0` line and I can't seem to fathom why.

> Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'alpha'

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `.alpha` on the function `itemOneDelete`. What you probably want instead is:

```
sender.alpha = 0
```

Or, if it's a different button (not `sender`), use that `UIButton`'s variable name.

You may also want to look at `.hidden` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-hidden

Comment: I tried `sender.alpha = 0` but the button was still appearing, I also tried `.hidden` however I got the same error.

Comment: Did you do `.hidden = true`? If so, I suggest you include enough code to reproduce the issue then (see: [mre]).

Comment: I've tried using `.hidden = true` as shown here: `@IBAction func itemOneDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if self.itemOneLabel.text == "" {
                itemOneDelete.hidden = true
            }` however I just receive this error - `Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'hidden'`

Comment: You've made the same mistake that I explained in my answer again. `itemOneDelete` is not a button -- it's the name of a function. You have to actually use the name of the UIButton's variable. If it's the same as `sender` (which may or may not be true), you could do `sender.hidden = true`